# Filtered multiple returned docs in mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to perform a query which returns back a document each time. The problem is that some docs have multiple instances in the database. So instead of getting one doc with a query I am getting multiple results. Thus I am trying to use find_one method which return the first query match. However, changing from find to find_one method I am facing a new problem. My code is the following:

```
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open('ids.txt')]

list_names = []
names= open('name.txt', 'w')
for x in range(0,3000):
  id = int(lines[x])
  print x ,'  ',lines[x]
  for cursor in collection.find_one({"_id.uid": id}):
      name = cursor['screenname']
      print name
      list_names.append(name)
  names.write("%s\n" % name)
names.close()
```

I have a list of ids and I want to return the correspondant names from mongoDb. However, I am getting `name = cursor['screenname']
  TypeError: string indices must be integers

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: seems like variable cursor is string, I suggest to try name = cursor[0], or name = cursor, or add before problem lines of code pdb.set_trace() to see what actually cursor is and how to handle it

Comment: Why in the case of find() it works fine??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find_one method does not return a cursor. It returns the document itself.

```
session = self.sessions.find_one({'_id': session_id})
print session # must print your document
```